# How copy GotFocus value to new Combobox? .NET wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events, combobox

In XAML file I have ComboBox like this:

```
<ComboBox Name="please" GotFocus="JutstDoIt">
    <!-- some ComboBoxItems -->
</ComboBox>
```

In C# file I want to copy GotFocus value from "please" to new ComboBox

```
//ninja code
ComboBox powerranger= new ComboBox();
powerranger.Name = "iwillbeaninja";
//other not important ninja code
powerranger.GotFocus = please.GotFocus; //It's not working!!!! :( 
//more ninja code
```

I know... It's event, not property.

Answer (score 0):

Okay! My senpai gave me an answer!

```
    powerranger.GotFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(NameOfFunction);
```

It's good!